# Does the colour of the eraser matter?

Tags: erasers

Today I saw that erasers can also be of [black colour](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B073B8HKJM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). Would the colour matter in terms of better cleaning/erasing? Can a black eraser perform better that a white one?

According to [this article](https://www.thespruce.com/best-erasers-4589998),

> because of this eraser’s black color, you can expect your paper to
> stay clean and smudge-free, no matter how many times you need to erase
> a mark.

Comment: A Google search for the quote shows the same link, but I couldn't find the text or the product anywhere on the page.  That Staedtler eraser wasn't among the listed products.  The quoted statement makes no sense.  Perhaps a reviewer speculated that but it doesn't appear to be a manufacturer claim.  Maybe The Spruce got pushback on the statement and removed the review from the article.

Comment: @fixer1234 Staedtler wasn't there ever. It is of black color hence I just posted it's link. Text is still there. I just checked.

Comment: OK found the text on the Sakura eraser.  Yeah, that makes no sense.  Reviewers like to add some positive verbiage about each product so it looks like a balanced review, or there was a reason they selected the product for review other than it happened to be at their local store.  That writer probably didn't think the statement through.  It's possible that it happens to be a good eraser, but not because it's black.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color isn't really what matters, its the quality and type of eraser. Almost all erasers are dyed, so that's the only thing that effects the color. Depending on the materials you're using and types of canvas/paper, different erasers will work better.  So if the black eraser was better quality, then yes, but overall, the color means nothing.

Comment: Does it mean that the quote from the above blog is baseless?

Comment: I've always found the quality of erasers to be a key factor as well. 
Buying cheap erasers from the dollar store, compared to buying a named brand quality eraser. Makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl yeah, the color has no meaning.

Comment: @Lyssagal,  yeah thats what im saying. buying a Pink Peral vs a Tombow, youre definitely gonna see a difference.